# Error uploading non image files with paperclip in rails 4.2

Tags: paperclip, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am getting this error while uploading non-image files through paperclip.

`Paperclip error - NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError`

Here is my model code:

```
has_attached_file :attachment, :styles => { :medium => "236x236>", :thumb => "150x150>", :large => "1000x500" }
```

Here is the version of my gems: `paperclip (4.2.1) activemodel (>= 3.0.0) activesupport (>= 3.0.0) cocaine (~> 0.5.3) mime-types`

It works fine if I remove the styles from model. But I need to resize the images as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove styles from model. The error is due to fact that when you upload non-image file, paperclip send this file to imageMagick for resizing according to style specified. As file is not image file, so imageMagick failed to convert file to given resolution and system crashed.

You may seprate fields for image and non-image attachments.

```
has_attached_file :image_attachment, :styles => { :medium => "236x236>", :thumb => "150x150>", :large => "1000x500" }
has_attached_file :attachment
```

For image attachment field, specify styles and dont specify styles for non-image attachment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that will not help as I can not have separate columns for images and non image attachments.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `before_post_process` model hook. It allows you to change or cancel the image processing. From an example described here https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#events

> if you return false (specifically - returning nil is not the same) in a before_filter, the post processing step will halt.

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :asset, styles: {thumb: "100x100#"}

  before_post_process :skip_for_audio

  def skip_for_audio
    ! %w(audio/ogg application/ogg).include?(asset_content_type)
  end
end
```

Comment: By the way in case anyone is wondering this method works perfectly, and I'm using it in production for weeks now.